# create form field what is the best way in symfony2

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I am new to symfony and currently i am doing one project in symfony2 
but i am not able to understand form builder and also it is complicated in symfony2. 
 Is it necessary to use form builder, can't we use normal html in twig?

Answer (score 0):

You dont't have to use Form component. If you don't, you obviously write native HTML forms yourself.

If you prefer to code that way your forms, I think you shouldn't use Symfony but rather a light framework like Silex (based on Symfony components).